# Syncfusion EJ2 Line Chart Tooltip Currency with commas

Tags: javascript, linechart, ej2-syncfusion, syncfusion-chart

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kindersingh/5eb3hzts/1/

```
var chart = new ej.charts.Chart({
    primaryXAxis: {
        title: 'Years',
        lineStyle: { width: 0 },
        labelFormat: 'y',
        intervalType: 'Years',
        valueType: 'DateTime',
        edgeLabelPlacement: 'Shift'
    },
    primaryYAxis:
    {
        title: 'Currency ($)',
        // minimum: 0, maximum: 20, interval: 2,
        labelFormat: 'C0'
    },
    series: [
        {
            type: 'StepLine',
            dataSource: chartData, xName: 'x', yName: 'y',
            width: 2, name: 'China',
            marker: {
                visible: true, width: 10, height: 10
            },
        },
        {
            type: 'StepLine',
            dataSource: chartData, xName: 'x', yName: 'y1',
            width: 2, name: 'Australia',
            marker: {
                visible: true, width: 10, height: 10
            },
        },
        {
            type: 'StepLine',
            dataSource: chartData, xName: 'x', yName: 'y2',
            width: 2, name: 'Japan',
            marker: {
                visible: true, width: 10, height: 10
            },

        },
    ],
    title: 'Unemployment Rates 1975-2010',
    tooltip: {
        enable: true,
        
    }
}, '#element');
```

I want to show Currency in a line chart for syncfusion EJ2 Line chart with proper commas.

I have tried putting a custom function for Tooltip.format and also tried a custom function for Charts.PrimaryYAxis.labelFormat but it is giving an error.

Also tried Data Label formats
https://ej2.syncfusion.com/javascript/documentation/chart/data-labels#format
but not getting commas.

How to put commas with currency? Is there an in-built way?

How to do it via custom functions without an in-built way?